# How do I implement a ConcurrentBag collection with different types?

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety

I need to implement a collection of collections, and since I need the collections to be thread-safe, it was recommended to me to use a ConcurrentBag.  However, I am going in circles because I need my collection to contain ConcurrentBags with different types, i.e., I will need to add ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentBag to another ConcurrentBag, but that doesn't work since I have to declare a Type for the ConcurrentBag that contains the others.  So, my question:  Is this a valid path to follow?  If not, how do I best implement a collection of collections of different types in a way that is thread-safe?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about creating it of type "Object" you can literally store anything as type Object. (ConcurrentBag<Object>)

Comment: I didn't want to get into a lot of casting, but that's a potential option.

Comment: You cant have mixed collection without casting. (at least I am not awere of any method allowing it)

Comment: What is common between the different types that you will be putting in the ConcurrentBags? This seems like an interface might be a good solution. Make an `iMyBagItem` interface, and implement it on all the types that need to go in a bag. Also make a `myInnerBag : ConcurrentBag<iMyBagItem>, iMyBagItem`. In the end, you will need to do casting before using them as the concrete type, but this will allow them to be used in a more general sense.

Comment: I like your idea about interfaces.  I was trying an interface as T but must have done something wrong.  I'll post what I come up with.